# Unable to connect to cassandra by java client through external ip

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I'm able to connect to cassandra docker instance using external ip with CQLSH but it is failing to connect from java client.

Server logs:

`Server.java:156 - Starting listening for CQL clients on /0.0.0.0:9042 (unencrypted)...`

Error from application:
`Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /14.24.34.44:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/14.24.34.44:9042] Cannot connect))`

Cassandra version used: 3.11.1

Comment: Can you show the output of "nodetool status"

Comment: Also provide the command you used to start Cassandra using docker and also the cqlsh command that was successfully able to connect from outside

Comment: did you map ports via Docker?

Comment: This happened when i tried to run two nodes on the same host, then i have installed nodes separatly in separate host. It worked !